How to do a Type Guard check on an Indexed Property
I have a nestedObj type which uses indexed signature as so:
type nestedObj = {[key: string]: nestedObj} | {[key: string]: number}

How would I create a type guard for this nestedObj type?
  const isNestedObj = (obj: any): obj is nestedObj => {
      if (obj === null || obj === undefined)
         return false;

      ??????
      
      return true;
  }


========= EDIT ===========
Sorry here is more information. The nested Obj is of the following
const testObj1 = { a: { b: { c: 42 } } };
const testObj2 = { ab: { bc: { cd: { d: 2 } } } };
const testObj3 = { xy: 3};

The object should only have exactly ONE key.
We do indeed also need to check if obj is a non-null object.
I had another go at it and came up with something like this
const isNestedObj = (obj: any): obj is nestedObj => {
    // terminating conditions
    if (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null || obj === undefined)
        return false
    
    // if number of keys is not exactly 1
    const objKeys = Object.keys(obj);
    if (objKeys.length !== 1)
        return false
    
    // if the next nested object is a number, return true
    if (typeof obj[objKeys[0]] === 'number')
        return true

    else return isNestedObj(obj[objKeys[0]]);
}

Seems to work for me, but not sure if this is the optimal solution

Your type nestedObj (you usually want to spell type alias names starting with a Capital) is infinitely recursive meaning any object assigned to it is valid. Therefore, there is no real criteria for a type guard.

You could check if the obj is not a number, then check of the object has keys inside it.

@Behemoth, but shouldn’t something like {‘isConnected’: true} return as false since it’s a key of value Boolean?

Are you sure you want {[key: string]: nestedObj} | {[key: string]: number} and not {[key: string]: nestedOb | number}?

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

(see prev comment) Where in that question would "number of keys is exactly one" matter at all? That has nothing to do with the type. You need to write that in the question verbally if it's a requirement.

@jcalz you are right, my bad I should add this in. The object needs to only have one key. I had though that the type I implemented
{[key: string]: nestedObj}
already suggests that there is always only one key, but now im starting to think that thats not the case.

@Bergi, looking at your suggestion, I think maybe you are right, {[key: string]: nestedOb | number} looks more like what I'm after. Strangely I tested out my edited solution changing the type from what i had previously to what you suggested here and it still works the same?

There is no TS type that means "exactly one key". You're using an index signature which doesn't mean that at all. How should we proceed? Someone can easily write a function which guarantees what you want, but using it as a type guard is problematic when the type doesn't really exist in TS. Why do you care about exactly one key? It's a weird requirement.

@jcalz thanks for the info, this definitely helps me understand better how this works. I've looked through your answer, and the logic definitely makes sense to me. If you post your answer I can accept it. As for exactly one key, unfortunately that was part of the requirement for the assignment

The type
type NestedObj = { [key: string]: NestedObj } | { [key: string]: number }

is a union of two object types, each with a string index signature. It means that a NestedObj must be an object whose properties all have to be of type number or all have to be of type NestedObj itself.  The number of properties is not restricted. That gives rise to the following behavior:
let n: NestedObj;

n = {}; // okay
n = { a: 0, b: 1, c: 2 }; // okay
n = { a: {}, b: {}, c: {} }; // okay
n = { a: { d: 0 }, b: { e: 1 }, c: { f: {} } }; // okay

n = { a: 0, b: 1, c: "abc" }; // error, string is not allowed
n = { a: 0, b: 1, c: {} }; // error, mix of numbers and objects
n = { a: { d: 0 }, b: { e: 1 }, c: { f: { g: "abc" } } }; // error, nested string

Note that the stated requirement that "the object should only have exactly ONE key" is not enforced by this type.
So either we have to take your type at face value and write a type guard function for it, or we have to write a function that verifies your requirement but not treat it as a type guard function for that type. I'm going to do the former.
The requirement that an object contain exactly one key isn't easily represented in TypeScript. Unless there's an overwhelmingly important use case for it, it would be better to relax the requirement or change the data structure to something enforceable, like [string, ...string[], number], and write ["a", "b", "c", 0] instead of  {a:{b:{c:0}}}.

Again, I'm going to write a custom type guard function that detects if an input is a valid NestedObj without caring about number of keys.  Here's one approach:
const isNestedObj = (obj: any): obj is NestedObj => {
  if (!obj) return false;
  if (typeof obj !== "object") return false;
  const values = Object.values(obj);
  if (values.every(v => typeof v === "number")) return true;
  return values.every(isNestedObj);
}

Here we make sure that obj is a nonnull object first. Then we use Object.values() to get all the property values of the object.  If every property is a number, then the test passes. Otherwise, we recurse to see if every property is a NestedObj.
This gives consistent behavior with the above tests:
console.log(isNestedObj({})) // true
console.log(isNestedObj({ a: 0, b: 1, c: 2 })) // true
console.log(isNestedObj({ a: {}, b: {}, c: {} })) // true
console.log(isNestedObj({ a: { d: 0 }, b: { e: 1 }, c: { f: {} } })) // true

console.log(isNestedObj({ a: 0, b: 1, c: "abc" })) // false
console.log(isNestedObj({ a: 0, b: 1, c: {} })) // false
console.log(isNestedObj({ a: { d: 0 }, b: { e: 1 }, c: { f: { g: "abc" } } })); // false

Note that the above function will fail to run if the passed-in object is actually circular, like:
const o: NestedObj = { a: {} };
o.a = o;
console.log(isNestedObj(o)) //  TOO MUCH RECURSION;

If you need to account for this, you'd have to make isNestedObj() more complex to keep track of the objects it's already seen, so it can exit early if it enters a loop. I won't do that here.

Note that if you try to enforce the "exactly one key" rule in a type guard function while keeping the type the same, you can get weird behavior:
const isNestedObj = (obj: any): obj is NestedObj => {
  if (!obj) return false;
  if (typeof obj !== "object") return false;
  const values = Object.values(obj);
  if (values.length !== 1) return false; // exactly one key
  if (values.every(v => typeof v === "number")) return true;
  return values.every(isNestedObj);
}

const o = Math.random() < 0.99 ? { a: 1, b: 2 } : "abc";
if (!isNestedObj(o)) {
  o // "abc"
  console.log(o.toUpperCase()) // 99% chance of a runtime error
}

The value {a: 1, b: 2} is a perfectly valid NestedObj according to the type. But isNestedObject({a: 1, b: 2}) now returns false. If isNestedObject is a type guard function, then TypeScript understands that to mean that !isNestedObject(o) implies that o is not a NestedObj.  And so in the above example, TypeScript will incorrectly conclude that when o must be "abc".
There are ways you can try to work around this, by making the type guard function "one sided" as described in microsoft/TypeScript#15048, or you could try to fight with the type system to come up with a type that only accepts objects with one property, as discussed at typescript restrict count of object's properties.  But that makes things more complicated and I'll consider it out of scope here.
Playground link to code

You can search for objects traversing the object keys:
type NestedObj = {[key: string]: NestedObj} | {[key: string]: number}

const isNestedObj = (obj: any): obj is NestedObj => {
    if (obj === null || obj === undefined) {
        return false;
    }
    return Object.keys(obj).find(k => typeof obj[k] === "object") !== undefined;
}

function test(obj: any) {
  if (isNestedObj(obj)) {
    type t = typeof obj['something']; // NestedObj | number
  } else {
    type t = typeof obj['something']; // any
  }
}

Maybe it would be better to find when is not nested:
type NotnestedObj = {[key: string]: number};
type NestedObj = {[key: string]: NestedObj} | NotnestedObj;

const isNotNestedObj = (obj: any): obj is NotnestedObj => {
    if (obj === null || obj === undefined) {
        return false;
    }
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    const allKeysAreNumbers = keys.filter(k => typeof obj[k] === "number").length === keys.length;
    return allKeysAreNumbers;
}

function test(obj: any) {
  if (isNotNestedObj(obj)) {
    type t = typeof obj['something']; // number
  } else {
    type t = typeof obj['something']; // any
  }
}


k => typeof obj[k] === "object" does not look like a sufficient condition for NestedObj properties. Also why check only one? And why reject empty objects?

Sorry, what do you mean by why check only one? Only one key? If one of the keys has a nested object, you get NestedObj. This should work for empty objects because typeof {} is "object".

Added a new version, but please provide more details so we can help you.

added some more details, hopefully it helps

Your new solution looks good to me :) You can post your self-answer.

@RemoH.Jansen {} is assignable to the NestedObject type but is rejected by your isNestedObj function. {x: 1} is assignable to NestedObject but is rejected. { x: {}, y: false } is not assignable to NestedObject but would be accepted by your "guard".
